# Saving timestamp causing issues - React/Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to send date and time from react to spring boot. In spring boot it gets deserialized in to Timestamp and then I save in to MySQL. But it is not saving correctly.
Not Saving correctly as in it is not saving in UTC time.
For example, from front end the time is sent as      `2021-11-21T00:00:00000Z` to the API,
in the Rest API Endpoint, if I print the timestamp, it will show as `2021-11-21T03:30:00000Z` if the timezone offset is +3:30. But I am using toISOString() to convert the time to UTC but is still not getting the correct value.

From react side, I have tried:

```
.toISOString()
```

I have tried this, it gives me date-time in format such as `2021-11-21T00:00:00000Z`.
I have tried the above and without the Z even, but In spring boot, the time is shown as

```
2021-11-21T03:30:00000
```

if the timezone offset is +3:30.
I am not able to figure out where is the issue here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not saving correctly"?

Does it throw some sort of Exception?

Does it save, but with the wrong value?

Can you show us the code that saves it?

Comment: For saving, it is normal .save() method of jpa.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you.

```
let date = new Date(your_date).getTime();
your_date = date.toString();
```

Comment: Actually, in react side I am converting the date to UTC using toISOString(). The problem is coming in Spring side as there it is adding the offset automatically.